# How to correctly use a series of independent if statements in python to get correct output?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am aware of the if-elif-else route but I felt this should work too.
please help me find my mistake. Made several attempts and finally no longer getting syntax or indentation errors but still getting wrong output.

My code:

```
cars = [ 'Audi' , 'bMw' , 'mercedes' , 'toyota' , 'soobie' ]

for car in cars:
    if car.lower() == 'bmw':
        print(car.upper())
        print("Your car's fast")

    if car.lower() == 'soobie':
        print("Subaru")
        print("You're probably a ricer")

    if car.lower() != 'bmw' and car.lower() in cars != 'soobie':
        print(car.title())
        print("Good choice!")
```

Intended output:

> Audi
>
> Good choice!
>
> BMW
>
> Your car's fast
>
> Mercedes
>
> Good choice!
>
> Toyota
>
> Good choice!
>
> Subaru
>
> You're probably a ricer

Answer (score 1):

your wrong output is because of third if statement. It can be corrected as follows with elif.

```
cars = [ 'Audi' , 'bMw' , 'mercedes' , 'toyota' , 'soobie' ]

for car in cars:
    if car.lower() == 'bmw':
        print(car.upper())
        print("Your car's fast")

    elif car.lower() == 'soobie':
        print("Subaru")
        print("You're probably a ricer")

    elif car.lower() != 'bmw' and car.lower() != 'soobie':
        print(car.upper())
        print("Good choice!")
```

Comment: Really appreciate it but  could you also  please explain the problem with my logic so as to avoid such errors in the future and also  how to solve this with ONLY if statements